# lapply function /loops on list of lists R

Tags: r, list, loops, lapply

I know this topic appeared on SO a few times, but the examples were often more complicated and I would like to have an answer (or set of possible solutions) to this simple situation. I am still wrapping my head around R and programming in general. So here I want to use `lapply` function or a simple loop to `data` list which is a list of three lists of vectors.

```
data1 <- list(rnorm(100),rnorm(100),rnorm(100))
data2 <- list(rnorm(100),rnorm(100),rnorm(100))
data3 <- list(rnorm(100),rnorm(100),rnorm(100))

data <- list(data1,data2,data3)
```

Now, I want to obtain the list of means for each vector. The result would be a list of three elements (lists).

I only know how to obtain list of outcomes for a list of vectors and

```
for (i in 1:length(data1)){
        means <- lapply(data1,mean)
}
```

or by:

`lapply(data1,mean)`

and I know how to get all the means using `rapply`:

`rapply(data,mean)`

The problem is that rapply does not maintain the list structure.
Help and possibly some tips/explanations would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

We can loop through the list of list with a nested `lapply/sapply`

```
 lapply(data, sapply, mean)
```

It is otherwise written as

```
 lapply(data, function(x) sapply(x, mean))
```

Or if you need the output with the `list` structure, a nested `lapply` can be used

```
 lapply(data, lapply, mean)
```

Or with `rapply`, we can use the argument `how` to get what kind of output we want.

```
  rapply(data, mean, how='list')
```

If we are using a `for` loop, we may need to create an object to store the results.

```
  res <- vector('list', length(data))
  for(i in seq_along(data)){
    for(j in seq_along(data[[i]])){
      res[[i]][[j]] <- mean(data[[i]][[j]])
    }
   }
```

Comment: wow, this is great (and somehow completely unintuitive to me, as i learned traditional loops first). just to grasp the idea, would you mind showing how it would look like in traditional for loop? that would help me to get idea about the indexing structure in case i need to apply some more complicated functions

Comment: why do you use `seq_along` instead of for instance `length` ? does it matter?

Comment: @Anna It is by practise.  I think `1:length` can fail in some cases.  For example, `l1 <- list();1:length(l1)#
[1] 1 0; seq_along(l1)#
integer(0)`

Comment: @akrun i know this is 5 years old but i this is so helpful i had to thank you anyway!

Comment: amazing. just amazing. many thx.